# orocommerce install failed you have requested a non-existent parameter "web_backend_prefix"

Tags: orocommerce

I done all steps to install orocommerce on azure CentOS and nginx.
So now i got the following error after

$ ./bin/console oro:install --env=prod --timeout=900

"In ParameterBag.php line 102:
You have requested a non-existent parameter "web_backend_prefix".

Have anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you get the source code (if GitHub - what repository, tag/branch, if download - what website and version)? Based on the error text it seems like it might be OroPlatform or OroCRM application, not OroCommerce.